# how to get the timestamp values in new york time zone in android?

Tags: android, datetime, timezone

below is my android code by which I need to get the timestamp value(value is coming from web server) in New York timezone. Please help me out because system is converting time to server timezone.

```
long startTime = Long.valueOf(appObj.getString("Unix_timestamp"))*1000;
Date fromDateObj = new java.util.Date(startTime);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();

sdf.applyPattern("HH");
fromHour = Integer.valueOf(sdf.format(fromDateObj));
sdf.applyPattern("mm");
fromMin = Integer.valueOf(sdf.format(fromDateObj));
```

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify desired timezone for `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much GrAnd. you saved my life. you rocked.